# Did Endeavor ever fight All for One?

Tags: my-hero-academia

I'm watching the anime series and I have no idea what happened in the manga. In another topic here I asked [Why if Endeavor solved more crimes than All Might He isnt considered the number one hero](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46722/why-if-endeavor-solved-more-crimes-than-all-might-he-isnt-considered-the-number) . I know All Might defeated All for One (I can't recall if he told that in the anime or if I readed it online).

I wonder if Endeavor ever fought All for One, and if he did, did he do well? That's my question. If that happened that could explain why one it's considered the number one hero perhaps.

Comment: The existence of All for One is unknown to most people. Infact, the first fight between All Might and All for one, its reault and the injury to All Might is known to selsect few. Endeavour being ranked 2 is most likely a multidimensional poll, where different factors are majored. I aalmost imagine the ranking similar to how different publications rate Universities these days. So Endeavour may outahine All might in one respect, he loses out in others (Brute Strength, Likeability etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reference in the manga, except maybe for a tiny bit, see edit at the end of post. Manga spoilers ahead. But just as Arcane indicated, All For One is no Gentle Criminal but a serious opponent who goes for the kill if he sees it fitting.

It is explained in the Manga that

> All for One has been like the boss of the mafia in the past, distributing Quirks among his underlings and himself as he liked. Not to mention that he set up the kid of the previous power holder of All Might's quirk to want to kill All Might. We basically know that All for One is evil incarnate regarding the series.

He may has no "death touch" like Overhaul, but given the damage he inflicted to All Might and

> the previous power owners of All Mights quirk

if he ever would have fought Endeavor, it surely would have been mentioned, as surviving a fight with All for One is a feat in itself and requires a lot of luck.

However,

> since All for One is merely imprisoned,

it is a possibility that he will fight Endeavor in the future.

> A prison break would be a typical trope for a series with super villains. (Also that way that the hero killer glanced at All for One gives me hope.) At that point Endeavor would possibly still be #1 hero and see it as his upmost important duty, as the new symbol of piece, to contain him again. I would gamble on Endeavor to die trying.

**EDIT:** As I was hinted by a comment, there is this one occasion starting around chapter 85

> Where All for One, who was still on the run at the time, got apprehended by the heroes. This happens in chapter 93: All for One gets attacked by some of the heroes after he fought a while with All Might and tried to break him psychologically. Other heroes evacuate civilians on the stage that prevented All Might from going all out. In particular, Endeavor unleashes some flames on All for One, which he dispels with ease. Endeavor also encourages All Might verbally. He was, together with the other heroes, just giving All Might a minute to catch his breath and rescue the civilians, All for One didn't even bother attacking Endeavor. I would hardly call this a fight rather than interfering in All Might's fight with All for One.

Comment: I havent read the manga, but I found this wikia which claims they did? http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Enji_Todoroki  "Endeavor along with Edgeshot and Kamui Woods head towards All Might's location after defeating apprehending the Noumus. Endeavor reaches the location and launches his flames strike at All For One, but All For One uses his blast wave attack to swat away the flames with ease"

Comment: @Pablo You are right that Endeavor attacked All for One on that occasion, but I wouldn't go as far to call it a fight. I updated my answer accordingly.